# Why do ecmascript5 says && logical operators will throw a ReferenceError exception if either operand is undefined?

Tags: javascript

In http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11
it says:
"The production LogicalANDExpression : LogicalANDExpression && BitwiseORExpression is evaluated as follows:

```
Let lref be the result of evaluating LogicalANDExpression.
Let lval be GetValue(lref)."
```

And 8.7.1 GetValue (V) :"If IsUnresolvableReference(V), throw a ReferenceError exception."

Through the link to IsUnresolvableReference(V) I found:"IsUnresolvableReference(V). Returns true if the base value is undefined and false otherwise."

But I have tested in ie and firefox,none of them throw a ReferenceError exception when either operand is undefined .Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: I get reference errors, what tests are you trying

Comment: [8.7 The Reference Specification Type](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7): *"A base value of undefined indicates that the reference could not be resolved to a binding..."* You're confusing an existing reference to the value `undefined`, and the use of the language as described in that part of the spec.

Comment: I heartily endorse reading the spec. It's weird and twisted, but getting familiar with it can help resolve lots of confusion as you get more experience with the language.

Comment: @Patrick Evans var a=undefined,b=3;alert(a&&b);

Comment: Take off the `var a=undefined` as that is defining the variable and giving it a reference of the `undefined` object. So in that instance the variable is resolvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "base value" of a reference is not simply the value of a variable. It's the *reference* to the variable. In simple terms, that part of the spec is talking about an undefined variable (or non-existent global symbol).

The reason for this behavior is to address a long-standing complaint about JavaScript semantics. Without "strict" mode, code that makes *assignment* references to non-existent variables results in no errors. Thus, simple typographical errors can be difficult to find.

Even with "strict" mode, of course, accidental references to non-existent *property names* will not throw exceptions.

Comment: The wording of the specification there is a little ambiguous, I'd agree.

Comment: *"Without "strict" mode, code that makes references to non-existent variables results in no errors..."* To be clear, that's only true for writes, not for reads.

Comment: You're in strict mode and you're reading a non-existent variable. Without strict mode writing to non-existent variables will not cause an error, but reading still will. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DJGrv

Comment: @squint got it - sorry I read your comment incorrectly. Yes, you're right; I'll update the answer.

Comment: So if I use "var b;alert(b&&b);" ,then b is a existent global symbol ,which will not cause a ReferenceError exception;If I use "alert(b&&b);" directly,then b is a "non-existent global symbol" ,which the word "undefined" in that part of es5 means.Is it right?